# Using the argparse output to call functions

Tags: python, command-line, parameters, arguments, argparse

Currently my code looks like this. It allows me to parse multiple parameters my program script gets. Is there a different way that is closer to 'best practices'? I haven't seen code actually using the output of `argparse`, only how to set it up.

```
def useArguments():
    x = 0
    while x <= 5:
        if x == 0:                      
            if args.getweather != None:
                getWeather(args.getweather)
        if x == 1:
            if args.post != None:
                post(args.post)
        if x == 2:
            if args.custompost != None:
                custompost(args.custompost)
        if x == 3:
            if args.list != None:
                listAccounts(args.list)
        if x == 4:
            if args.add != None:
                addAccount(args.add[0])
        if x == 5:
            if args.edit != None:
                editAccount(args.edit[0])
        x = x + 1    


if __name__ == '__main__':

    updateConfig()

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Post Yahoo weather to Twitter.', epilog="Report any bugs to example@email.com", prog='Program')

    parser.add_argument('-a', '--add', nargs=1, help='Add a new account. Use the desired account name as an argument.')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--edit', nargs=1, choices=accountListSTR[:-1], help='Edit an account. Use the desired account name as an argument.')
    parser.add_argument('-g', '--getweather', nargs='*', choices=accountListSTR, help='Get weather and post here. Specify account(s) as argument. Use "all" for all accounts. If you specify multiple accounts, separate by a space NOT a comma.')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--post', nargs='*', choices=accountListSTR, help='Post weather to Twitter. Specify account(s) as argument. Use "all" for all accounts. If you specify multiple accounts, separate by a space NOT a comma.')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--custompost', nargs=2, help='Post a custom message. Specify an account then type the message. Make sure you use "" around the message. Use "all" for all accounts.')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', action='store_const', const='all', help='List all accounts.')
    parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 0.3.3')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    useArguments()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could supply a custom [action](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#action) for an argument by, and I quote:

> passing an object that implements the
>   Action API. The easiest way to do this
>   is to extend argparse.Action,
>   supplying an appropriate `__call__`
>   method. The `__call__` method should
>   accept four parameters:
>
> 1. **parser**: The ArgumentParser object which contains this action.
> 2. **namespace**: The namespace object that will be returned by `parse_args()`. Most actions add an attribute to this object.
> 3. **values**: The associated command-line args, with any type-conversions applied.(Type-conversions are specified with the type keyword argument to `add_argument()`.
> 4. **option_string**: The option string that was used to invoke this action. The option_string argument is optional, and will be absent if the action is associated with a positional argument.

Comment: In what situations would this be the best method? I can't see a use for all that extra code. But then again, I barely used Classes so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @vlad, it might be used to automatically call a function when an argument is supplied, which is what you're doing will all your boilerplate -- you'd just have to make the functions be the `__call__` methods of appropriate subclasses of `argparse.Action`. But if you don't "get" object-oriented programming, that's OK, you can do it your way (though that loop and `if x ==` checks are really redundant in any case - just do one after the other the checks for what arguments are present possibly follower by the appropriate calls, there's no added value in the other boilerplate you use).

Comment: Accepted this answer because it answers my question. I *might* end up trying this to learn how it works; but it will require many changes in how my code currently works (especially the functions listed there).

Thanks!

Comment: I love the cleanliness of this approach, but the limitation is that the custom action begins before remaining arguments are parsed (ie., they're not in `Namespace()`), so it's not clear how optional flags could affect the behavior of the custom action.

Answer (score 6):

See http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands:

> One particularly effective way of handling sub-commands is to combine the use of the `add_subparsers()` method with calls to `set_defaults()` so that each subparser knows which Python function it should execute.

In a nutshell:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

weather_parser = subparsers.add_parser('get-weather')
weather_parser.add_argument('--bar')
weather_parser.set_defaults(function=get_weather)  # !

args = parser.parse_args(['get-weather', '--bar', 'quux'])
print args.function(args)
```

Here we create a subparser for the command `get-weather` and assign the function `get_weather` to it.

Note that the documentation says that the keyword/attribute is named `func` but it's definitely `function` as of argparse 1.1.

The resulting code is a bit too wordy so I've published a small package ["argh"](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argh) that makes things simpler, e.g.:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
add_commands(parser, [get_weather])
print dispatch(parser, ['get-weather', '--bar', 'quux'])
```

"Argh" can do more but I'll let stack overflow answer that. :-)

Comment: Concerning the recent edit by caffinatedmonkey ("I won't let this answer stack overflow" → "I'll let stack overflow answer that"). The new version sounds fine but I actually meant that the answer would become bloated had I stuffed too much information into the textarea. =)

Comment: Are you sure the `func`/`function` part is still true? `func` works fine for me...

Comment: Not only is the subparsing approach ugly, but it seems to just pass the task of argument parsing to a lower level--you either have to have separate functions to pass into each `func` that then calls your "real" functions, or your real functions have to take the generic args dict. I guess the former is fine for large programs, but it seems ridiculous to introduce so many extra layers to a small program. All the same, subparsers seem like the best option so far.

Comment: @RyneEverett actually that _argh_ library supports plain Python functions as commands by introspecting their signatures, so no dumb wrapper functions are required.

Comment: My critique wasn't leveled at *argh*, but I'll definitely be checking that out. *Argh* appears to be essentially a wrapper for *argparse* subparsers, so my annoyance with *argparse*'s boilerplate requirement still stands.

Comment: @RyneEverett that's exactly why I created _argh_ in the first place :) Argparse is very powerful but has a clumsy API which is hard to use and remember. Hence the abundance of various wrappers and alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

With the exception of `--version`, which is very commonly an option, the actions you've provided are better off treated as "subcommands".

I'm unaware of the argparse specifics, as I have yet to try Python 2.7, but you might take a look at the `svn` command as an example, here's some pseudocode for the command line:

```
myprog [--version] <command> [<command opts>...]
```

Where `<command>` in:

```
add|edit|getweather|post|custompost|list
```

And `<command opts>` are options specific to that command. Using optparse (which is similar), this would mean that your command would be returned in `args`, when calling `parse_args`, allowing you to do something like this:

```
opts, args = parser.parse_args()
if opts.version:
    ...
else:
    getattr("do_" + args[0])(*args[1:])
```

I find this pattern particularly useful for debugging, where I'd provide access to internal functions from the command line, and pass various arguments for testing. Adjust the selection of the command handler as appropriate for your own project.

Comment: `argparse` actually provides support for precisely this pattern. (`optparse` doesn't.) I'm still stuck on Python 2.6 myself so I don't know the specifics offhand either, but they're explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: What would be the advantage of doing this instead of just removing the `--` from my arguments. I guess to the end user it'd end up looking the same, right? I guess having it like that would make more sense for the user as well b/c they're not really running the program with custom parameters but rather telling it to do something.

Comment: @vlad003: That's right. The user of the program must select one and only one of those "options", so really they're commands to your program. Those commands however, do potentially take arguments. An alternative is to write seperate executable scripts for each command, perform arg parsing separately in each one, and call a common code base for implementation. Eg your scripts might be called: myprog-list, myprog-add, etc. However I might add, as you are using argparse from Python-2.7, that there could be very fancy argument handling already incorporated into that.