# argparse call a function after parsing other options

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Currently, I am using argparse to parse arguments and store flags as boolean options.  I then check to see which flag is set to true and execute that function.  Argparse parses an input file, which is opened and passed to the called function as an argument.

So:

```
parser.add_argument('input_data', action='store', help='some help')
parser.add_argument('outputname', action='store',default=None, help='some help')
parser.add_argument('--flag','-f', action='store_true', dest='flag', default=False, help='help!')
```

I have to open the input_data to read some information from it before the flag function is called.  This is currently implemented as:

```
if args.flag == True:
    array_out = flag(array_read_from_input)
    if args.outputname == None:
        name = 'Flag.tif'
```

It is possible to [subclass argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454934/using-the-argparse-output-to-call-functions) to have the action keyword call a function.

Is it possible to parse the input_data option, perform some processing, and then call the flag function without having nested if loops for each argument, eg., by subclassing argparse's action parameter?

Comment: Do not compare objects to `True` or `None`. Either use `is` or use the truthvalue of the object(thus it should be `if args.flag: ...` and `if args.outputname is None`). Also, you do know that you can create custom actions right? Just read the argparse documentation.

Comment: @Bakuriu "It is possible to subclass argparse to have the action keyword call a function." The question is not whether it is possible to create a custom action, but whether that action can be called after parsing and manipulating other args.

Comment: If you want to call it *after* parsing, then I do not understand what's the relationship of `argparse` to your question. That module is there just to parse the command line and eventually execute actions *during* parsing. Also, I don't understand what's wrong with the double `if`.
As a side note: nothing prohibits you to use a subclass of the [parser](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects) and reimplemente `parse_args` so that the function is called there, but you'll still have to put a double `if` there.

Comment: @Bakuriu if performing an action during parsing can I return a object to be passed to another argument for use during parsing?  The issue is not with a single double if, but an implementation that has 25+ flags.  A large code block is dedicated to if statements that, if possible, I want to remove as redundant.

Comment: I don't think you can "return an object", but creating a custom action you can do whatever you want with the `Namespace` and the parser, so instead of returning values from the function you can put them in the namespace. Anyway, maybe providing a slightly more complicated example that resembles more what you want to do might help us realize what you could do.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to parse the input_data option, perform some
>   processing, and then call the flag function without having nested if
>   loops for each argument, eg., by subclassing argparse's action
>   parameter?

As per your question;

```
class FooAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        << some processing of values >>
        array_out = flag(values)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, array_out)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input_data', action=FooAction, help='some help')
```