# Python Command Line Arguments: Calling a function

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse, optparse

So I'm stuck on a project I'm working on that involves the command line in python.

So basically, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a set of functions in a class, say,

```
def do_option1(self, param1, param2) :
    #some python code here

def do_option2(self, param1): 
    #some python code here

def do_option3(self, param1, param2, param3):
    #some python code here
```

And so basically, when a user puts `filename.py option2 param1` into the command line, I want it to call the function `do_option2` and pass the parameter, `param1`, to it.

Similarly, when a user puts `filename.py option3 param1 param2 param3`, I want it to execute the do_option3 function with the given parameters.

I know there are 2 modules in python called `argparse` and `optparse`, but I've had difficulty understanding the two and i'm not sure if either of the two alone will accomplish what I need done.

Comment: From a learning perspective, I'd suggest first getting your information directly from `sys.argv`.  You can use a sequence of `if` statements, or the dictionary dispatching.  If you need to add more options, then take the time to learn `argparse`.  Your problem fits the `subparsers` model nicely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `argparse` subcommand parsers

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = p.add_subparsers()

option1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('option1')
# Add specific options for option1 here, but here's
# an example
option1_parser.add_argument('param1')
option1_parser.set_defaults(func=do_option1)

option2_parser = subparsers.add_parser('option2')
# Add specific options for option1 here
option2_parser.set_defaults(func=do_option2)

option3_parser = subparsers.add_parser('option3')
# Add specific options for option3 here
option3_parser.set_defaults(func=do_option3)

args = p.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

Then each of your `do_option` functions would need to be rewritten slightly to take a single argument from which it can extract the values it needs. For example:

```
def do_option1(args):
    param1 = args.param1
    # And continue
```

Answer (score 6):

I use this template that may help you out.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--option1', help='description for option1')
parser.add_argument('--option2', help='description for option2')
parser.add_argument('--option3', help='description for option3')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.option1:
    ...do something

if args.option2:
    ...do something

if args.option3:
    ...do something
```

You can then run your script passing the arguments like this:

```
python script.py --option1 my-option1 --option3 my-option3 --option2 my-option2
```

Note that the position of the arguments is not important since you specify the name of the argument before its value.

Answer (score 4):

```
options = {
    'option_1': my_class.option_1,
    'option_2': my_class.option_2,
    'option_3': my_class.option_3,
}

option, params = sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:]
options[option](*params)
```

Should do the trick. You'll probably want to add some checking to make sure that the user is passing at least some arguments to your script.

Comment: I don't follow how this works (probably my own shortcoming) ... doesn't `sys.argv[0]` return the name of the script that was run, rather than a function?

Answer (score 2):

[Execute function via arg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251204/execute-function-via-arg)

As stated in the accepted answer, you can (ab?)use the `type` parameter of `add_argument` to execute a function.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('option2', type=interface.do_option2)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Good starting point but it would be preferable, I think, to go with [sub commands](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#sub-commands) (as in the second last example).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly pass in the parameters without using tags, you can just use the sys module: `sys.argv` will give you `['filename.py', 'option3', 'param1', 'param2', 'param3']` for the command line of `filename.py option3 param1 param2 param3`

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. So in my main function, I have,     
    interface = Interface()
    interface.prompt(">")
    interface.cmdloop("Starting prompt...") 

Interface is the class with the functions. 
So with sys.argv I can call a certain function and pass those arguments along with it, at the same time?

Comment: Just use an if statement to decide which function to call: `if sys.argv[1]=='option3':` , etc.

Comment: `sys.argv` has all of the command line elements in it, so you can parse from it anything that is added as arguments to the command line