# Calling a function using argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am trying to call the function addPXT through argparse when type -a. Its not doing that. Read another issue, there addPXT was not in colons, tried that it says addPXT is not callable.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a' ,action='store_const'  ,const='addPXT')
results = parser.parse_args()

def addPXT():
        print "hello"
```

---

```
    python script.py -a
```

Comment: Why did you think it *would* do that?

Comment: I am trying to call a function, read another issue. this was recommended

Comment: Could you link to that, and provide an actual [mcve]? By colons do you mean quotes?

Comment: *The const argument of add_argument() is used to hold constant values* -- Are you sure that should be the function name?

Comment: What is your goal? `argparse` is for parsing command line arguments and not for calling arbitrary functions. If `addPTX` is supposed to process an argument, for later use by your program, then great. But read how the [action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) keyword works. It has a specific role and it uses an [Action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action) object.

Comment: I want that when -a passed as a argument it should call the function addPXT(), that function further have variables which I can assign values through the dest value

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are a beginner with `argparse` and `python`, I'd recommend sticking with the default `store` action, which stores strings, and the boolean actions ('store_true/false').  Make sure you understand those first.

That said, here is a way of using `store_const` to call different functions:

```
In [131]: import argparse
```

define 2 functions:

```
In [132]: def act1():
     ...:     print('act1')
     ...:    
In [133]: def act2():
     ...:     print('act2')
     ...:     
In [134]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [135]: parser.add_argument('-a',action='store_const',default=act1,const=act2);
```

I define both the default and the const - and specify the functions, not their names.  Understanding the difference is important.

Try the default case:

```
In [136]: args=parser.parse_args([])
In [137]: print(args)
Namespace(a=<function act1 at 0xb07331dc>)
In [138]: args.a()
act1
```

Try the `-a` commandline case:

```
In [139]: args=parser.parse_args(['-a'])
In [140]: print(args)
Namespace(a=<function act2 at 0xb078c1dc>)
In [141]: args.a()
act2
```

If you have more arguments (dest), you could pass `args` to your function, if it is defined to accept them, `args.a(args)`.

The simpler boolean argument approach:

```
In [146]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [147]: parser.add_argument('-a',action='store_true');
In [148]: args=parser.parse_args([])
In [149]: print(args)
Namespace(a=False)
In [150]: if args.a:
     ...:     act2()
     ...: else:
     ...:     act1()
act1
# similarly for `['-a']`.
```

or if you accept strings, maybe even choices

```
if args.a == 'act1':
     act1()
elif ...
```

The primary purpose of `argparse` is to deduce what the user wants, and issue help and error messages.  Acting on that information is largely the responsibility of the rest your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251204/execute-function-via-arg I tried with type also didn't work for me.

Comment: Make sure you understand when the `type` function is executed. See my comment on the accepted answer of your link.

Comment: parser.add_argument('-a'       ,action='store_const',default='addPXT',const='test');
 I tried to use ur method, I am not able to give default and const as function names, its accepting as a string only. when I tries results.a() it says str not callable. On the other hand if i remove colons i get addPXT  not defined

Comment: `its accepting as a string only` - elaborate.  What's the error message?  You need to understand the difference between function names (references) and strings.  Strings aren't callable.  The end of my code shows how string values could be used.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PXT.py", line 17, in <module>
    parser.add_argument('-a'       ,action='store_const',default='addPXT',const=test);
NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Comment: def test():
        print "hello"

Comment: Define the functions first

Comment: thanks that's working.
but I would like to have a one liner

Answer (score 3):

`argparse` will call the `action` object during parsing but you need to supply something that looks like the `Action` class because the parser will use that object later. The [Action doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#action) says

> You may also specify an arbitrary action by passing an Action subclass
>   or other object that implements the same interface. The recommended
>   way to do this is to extend Action, overriding the **call** method and
>   optionally the **init** method.

So, create an `Action` subclass and have it call your function

```
import argparse
import sys

def addPXT():
    print "hello"

class FooAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        addPXT()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action=FooAction)
results = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `dest`option in the add_argument to be able to reference the option.

You will then need to test if the `-a` option was passed as argument. If so, then call the function.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a' ,dest="my_flag", action='store_const'  ,const=True)
results = parser.parse_args()

def addPXT():
    print "hello"

if results.my_flag:
    addPXT()
```

Comment: Whether this is the right answer depends on OP's intent. If OP wants to define an alternate action for the command parser, an `Action` object would be more appropriate.

Comment: Right, but as far as I know the `action` keyword does not support function calling in py3 https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

Comment: Use `action='store_true' to get a simple True/False flag.  For a beginner Python/argparse user simple True/False and string arguments are best.

Comment: Without the `dest`, `results.a` fetches the value.  Or use `('-a','--my_flag',...)`.

Comment: The `action` keyword expects a `Action`-like object which should do some preprocessing on the option before the parser continues on its way. Depending on what OP wants to do,  either your answer or something using an `Action` object is best.